# Typo3 / TS3Editor missing Code Completion

Tags: typo3

I'm using Typo3 9.2.0 and it looks like the Code Completion doesn't work for me.

I'm new at typo3 and if I understood right it should be implemented.

I searched on Google and watched the Typo Extension Repository but I didn't found an Extension with the searchword "completion" that does what I'm looking for.
What Extension or what way do I have to go to get it into the backend?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TYPO3 – TypoScript auto-complete in backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49307684/typo3-typoscript-auto-complete-in-backend)

Answer (score 0):

If you are missing the editor with syntax highlighting and codecompletion in the Backend, you may need to install the system extension cms-t3editor. If you are in composer mode, use this command:

```
composer require typo3/cms-t3editor
```

If you have installed TYPO3 in classic way, just activate that extension,